# Remove all elements with a class until the next element is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have the following HTML structure, (This cannot change).

```
<!-- Comment 1 -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list" style="padding-left: 0px;"></div> <!-- Main Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 20px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 40px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 60px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->

<!-- Comment 2 -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list" style="padding-left: 0px;"></div> <!-- Main Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 20px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 40px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->

<!-- Comment 3 -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list" style="padding-left: 0px;"></div> <!-- Main Div -->
<div class="ac_feed_item comments_v2_list reply" style="padding-left: 20px;"></div> <!-- Reply Div -->
```

I would like to remove, (via jQuery/Javascript), `<div> Comment 2` & all its "reply" divs (It does not have a parent child relationship, Each div is by itself, so I cannot use `.children` to traverse the DOM).

But `<div> Comment 3` should remain, as should `<div> Comment 1`.

So basically, I want to remove `comment 2` and all of its `.reply` (***which are not children***, They are individual divs).

I was thinking of using something like `.next()` with a `if()` & `.hasClass()` to see if we are at the end of the comment section we want to delete, but was having trouble with this.

Comment: Is the HTML structure always the same? I.e. comment 1 has three reply divs, comment 2 has two reply divs, and comment 3 has one reply div?

Comment: no its not, that will change depending on the amount of comments and replies. The above is just an example, it needs to be flexible.

Comment: How about the comments? Will they always be there as in your example?

Comment: the structure of the comments will be the same (ie class and style), and under each comment will be a unlimited amount of replies, there may also be a unlimited amount of comments.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the HTML comments `<!-- -->`

Comment: no they are just there for the question. @Nate B got it spot on, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery makes it pretty easy with the `.nextUntil()` method. [Documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

The example is included in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6vzU/).

The code is the following one:

```
// On click of a div which is not of class .reply
$('div.ac_feed_item.comments_v2_list:not(.reply)').click(function() {
    // Remove all divs after this, until a div that does not have `.reply` class
    $(this).nextUntil('div.ac_feed_item.comments_v2_list:not(.reply)').remove();
    // remove the main comment div
    $(this).remove();
});
```

​

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aexzm/ I gave the DIV and ID so you can see how to remove comment2. You wern't clear on what will drive the removing of the elements so I assuming that in some way you will convert $('#comment2') to $(this) in what ever you're using it in